# How to run a bash script from dockerfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, docker, dockerfile

I am using a bash script (`run.sh`) to run a python file (`calculate_ssp.py`). The code is working fine. The folder structure is given below

```
├── dataset
    └── dataset_1.csv
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── output
├── run.sh
├── scripts
│   ├── calculate_ssp.py
│   ├── __init__.py
```

The bash script is

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 -m scripts.calculate_ssp 0.5
```

Now, I am trying to run the bash script (`run.sh`) from the `Dockerfile`. The content of the Dockerfile is

```
#Download base image ubuntu 20.04
FROM ubuntu:20.04

#Download python
FROM python:3.8.5

ADD run.sh .

RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install rdkit-pypi

CMD ["bash", "run.sh"]
```

But, I am getting an error `/usr/local/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for 'scripts.calculate_ssp' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts')`

Could you tell me why I am getting the error (as the code is working fine from the bash script)?

Comment: Your Dockerfile never adds the Python script to the image.

Comment: Also, `FROM ubuntu:20.04` does not (I believe) do anything effective, as you immediately switch to the Python base image.

Comment: @thanks for your comment. Then should I remove `FROM ubuntu:20.04`? And, what I have to do solve the issu?

Comment: You have to add the `scripts` package to your image, just like you had to add `run.sh`.

Comment: Like this `ADD scripts.calculate_ssp.py`?

Comment: No, because `scripts.calculate_ssp.py` is not a file name.

Comment: Could you tell me what I have to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to package *all* the files required by your script in the image.  You can drop the Ubuntu base image, since it isn't used. (The `python` base image is based on some other image that already provides `bash`.)

```
#Download python
FROM python:3.8.5

RUN pip install pandas
RUN pip install rdkit-pypi

ADD run.sh .
ADD scripts/ ./scripts

CMD ["bash", "run.sh"]
```

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, since, I am saving the output (from `calculate_ssp.py`) file in the `output` folder. So, I also have to add `ADD output/ ./output`?

Comment: No, but that's a topic for another question. You'll need to create the directory inside the image, but then *mount* an external directory on that path when you create a container.

Comment: Opps I am getting a new error. The dataset file is not found! Code I used to get the dataset file inside the calculate_ssp.py is `dataset = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "dataset"), "dataset_1.csv"), index_col=None)`

Comment: Again, a topic for another question. The question asked above has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

In the Bash script, write a program that creates a file named Dockerfile. The contents of the Dockerfile should have the following commands:

First, the base image should install python3 via the FROM command. Then the rest of the Dockerfile should look like the following:

```
RUN pip install {{MODULES}}
CMD ["python", {{FILENAME}}]
```

`{{MODULES}}` should be replaced with the modules: `numpy, scipy, and pandas` all on one line. `{{FILENAME}}` should be replaced with `./main.pyv`

Comment: Yea this is a coding challenge from Coderbyte. I have it printing the hash but my answer isn't accepted. Do you know what is the expected hash value? to the character, exactly how should the Dockerfile look?